# Getting all commets for an event with FQL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

i am trying to list all comments for an event created by a certain page. I am getting the EID for for the event with a multiquery like this:

```
{ 'eids':'
SELECT eid, uid 
FROM event_member 
WHERE uid = 64565465464
'events':'
SELECT eid, name, venue, location, start_time, creator 
FROM event WHERE eid 
IN (SELECT eid FROM #eids) 
AND creator =  64565465464  ORDER BY start_time ASC'}
```

I am totally clueless how to get the comments for that event with that EID.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use the `stream` FQL table. The `source_id` on this table relates to the `eid` of the event table.

Example query via your above multi-query:

```
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (SELECT eid FROM #eids)
```

Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

Comment: I tried your query but not successful. I cannot get comments of this event: https://www.facebook.com/events/582252385180829